# Making SSRS reports equal size

Tags: visual-studio, layout, reporting-services, report

I have a report showing one graph, and another separate report showing another graph. I then have a "master" report which combines these two reports as subreports, side by side.

However, I don't seem to be able to easily make them the same size. This means that the master report looks a bit odd, as one subreport will be just a bit smaller than the other.

I can make them *roughly* the same size just by repeatedly adjusting the heights of the individual subreports until it looks "alright", but this method is never going to make things exact and is also very tedious.

Surely there's a way to make two reports exactly the same size so that they display fine when includes in the master report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While subreports aren't aware of each other during the render process, if you're dealing with fixed size elements like charts there's a simple way to accomplish this.

First, make sure you have the properties pane enabled.

[image: Enable Properties]

Then when you click on a chart you can set its height and weight numerically and be exact:

[image: Edit Size]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. One question though - for each report I have the overall report size set to 10"x10", and the plot set to 5"x5", yet the plot takes up the entire width of the report! It's not exactly a problem, it still looks fine in the browser, but I was just wondering if I'm missing something obvious or else why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Set the same size of subreports, but instead of using graphical designer, use properties on the right side. In master report you can mainly just set location of subreports, but size of subreport component does not count.

Answer (score 0):

Hard code the dimensions of your reports/graphs/charts in the properties pane. Make sure your background (parent) level is large enough to contain the other elements.